# BackStack fragment get touch or click , what is wrong with my code?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-fragments

Following code am using while am adding new fragment and adding old fragment to backstack but still old fragment in backstack get click ,what is wrong with my code?

```
getFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.content_frame, new XyzFragment())
                .addToBackStack(null)
                .commit();
```

Comment: Before you begin transaction do this android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    manager.popBackStack();

Answer (score 0):

use this, It is worked for me by using always "replace method" instead of "add method". I never used "add"

```
Fragment fragment = new YourFragment();
    FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    ft.addToBackStack("Frag");
    fragment.setArguments(null);
    ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment);
    ft.commit();
```

Comment: i dont want lost the state of fragment added in backstack